# Check if a string contains a certain character using recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I know how to check if a string contains a certain character like this:

```
charFound :: Char -> String -> Bool
charFound c s = c `elem` s
```

Now, how could I have the same approach using recursion?

Also, using Pattern Matching to check if one of the parameters is empty, I'm getting

*Parse Error In pattern: ' ' s*

```
charFound:: Char->String->Bool
charFound '' s = error "Something is empty." -- ERROR
charFound c "" = error "Something is empty." -- OK
```

Am I allowed to use the `_` to ignore a parameter with something that's not a list ?

**Update** Currently code

```
charFound :: Char->String->Bool
charFound c (x:xs)
   | c == x = True
   | xs == "" = False
   | otherwise = contido c xs
```

Also

```
charFound :: Char->String->Bool
charFound _ "" = False -- returns false if I type >  charFound 'a' "Leh"
charFound c (x:xs)
   | c == x = True
   | otherwise = contido c xs
```

Comment: `elem` is a recursive function. You can try implementing it, or checking in the documentation how it is implemented.

Comment: From LearnYouaHaskell.com: Recursion is actually a way of defining functions in which the function is applied inside its own definition

Comment: You're missing the empty list pattern match and instead have a funny-looking sms unnecessary test for the empty list in the non-empty case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can keep the same signature, because the function does the same thing.

```
charFound :: Char -> String -> Bool
```

When you are performing recursion you always want to make sure you consider your base case, in this case it would be when you are looking for a character in an empty String, which should obviously always return false.

```
charFound c "" = False
```

Now you have to consider the other case, where the String is not empty. If the string is not empty, then it is of the form `(x:xs)`, and if x equals our character then we return true, otherwise we check whether c is in xs.

```
charFound c (x:xs)
    | c == x = True
    | otherwise = charFound c xs
```

Alternatively,

```
charFound c (x:xs) = c == x || charFound c xs
```

---

Edit:
To answer your additional question about pattern matching, you are getting that warning because `''` is not a character! A character can never be empty, so you don't need to consider that possibility. 
Also, you definitely can use `_` to match on something that is not a list. You can use `_` to match any parameter you like. For example, the base case could have been written as

```
charFound _ "" = False
```

Because we don't actually need to know what the value of the character is when the String is empty, so we don't need to give it a name.

Comment: Thanks man. I added one more thing about Pattern Matching. Could you give me a hands up ?

Comment: Almost perfect. But when I type empty string I get "Exception: t4.hs:(26,1)-(28,29): Non-exhaustive patterns in function charFound"

Comment: You will have to have the base case in your function too. The `charFound c "" = False` should be right above the `charFound c (x:xs)`. That will mean that the base case is the first pattern that is tried, so you will never end up trying to take the head/tail of an empty list.